# DoctrineFixtures and Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried to load fixtures using Symphony 2.7.2 and got errors like thus:

```
    [InvalidArgumentException]                
  Could not find any fixtures to load in:   
  - src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/
```

I used the link below as guide, but it doesn't help to solve my problem! 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Have you had it?

Thanks

**here is my code:**

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\blog;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use AppBundle\Entity;

class LoadBlogData implements FixtureInterface {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $blog = new Blog();
        $blog->setTitulo('Phasellus tempus pretium tellus a convallis');
        $blog->setDescricao('Phasellus tempus pretium tellus a convallis. Curabitur a erat lorem. Morbi a nisi nec mauris consequat accumsan. Pellentesque lectus lectus, lobortis quis facilisis quis, imperdiet pharetra mauris. Quisque eleifend pretium lectus vel blandit. In tempus, lectus condimentum finibus vehicula, diam ex varius nunc, et suscipit turpis dui sit amet elit.');
        $blog->setConteudo("Suspendisse sit amet finibus velit. Suspendisse placerat pretium tellus, ut vehicula tortor malesuada ut. Maecenas ornare maximus sem eu interdum. Mauris at dolor est. Nam mollis velit augue, efficitur efficitur ligula malesuada a. Ut blandit neque urna, a rutrum lorem pretium id. Morbi mi ligula, facilisis et enim in, tristique efficitur enim. Vestibulum leo ipsum, facilisis ac lobortis et, tempus et tortor. Nullam sed mauris sed magna euismod vulputate vel sed nulla. Sed a nisl dolor. Nullam finibus cursus libero convallis pretium. Praesent nibh dolor, congue sit amet tempor sed, fringilla rhoncus dolor. Sed suscipit est erat, at congue sapien rhoncus eget.");

        $manager->persist($blog);
        $manager->flush();

    }
}
```

**my entity:**

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 */
class Blog {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
    protected $titulo;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=400)
    */
    protected $descricao;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(type="text")
    */
    protected $contudo;
 /** getters and setter goes here **/
```

**My command line on terminal (Mackbook - Yosemite)**

```
$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/ --append
```

Comment: If you have create a fixture, can you provide the code ? please

Comment: Please show us your code for loading fixtures, and where your fixtures are located.

Comment: Hi guys. Posted the code! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/ --append

> loading AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadBlogData
```

In LoadBlogData.php I used a wrong use import

```
use AppBundle\Entity;
```

The right syntax is like it:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Blog;
```

Symfony 2 is amazing!

thank you guys